# PHP ordering results in the code logic 

Tags: php, codeigniter

Ok I have a results set of takeaways that I am looping through, the takeaway objects have the following properties id, name, address, postcode, distance, mile_cost, pizza, chinese, indian, kebab. If they have a pizza menu fr exampe it will contain 1 or a 0 if not etc

I want to filter the results in order to get the closest single pizza, Chinese, Indian and kebab selling restaurants. But also filter the results so that it doesn't show results with a distance greater than 10 and greater than the individual takeaways max deliver distance.

I have to do this in the php code rather than the mysql query and I am kinda stumped as how to do it. This is what I have so far

```
 foreach($takeaway as $takeaway){

        $distance = $this->geozip->get_distance($location, $takeaway->postcode);//get the distance between the two postcodes 

        if($distance <= $takeaway->distance && $distance <= 10){

            $number = 0;

            echo $takeaway->name.' is '.$distance.'miles away <br />';

         ?>  
           <div class="takeaway_box">
               <div class="takeaway_box_band">Indian</div>

           </div>                
 <?php
        } 
    }
  ?>
```

I guess in order to get the closest single restaurant of each type I will have to find the ones with a distance closest to zero then order them some how?

Any help on how to do this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [array_filter](http://php.net/array_filter) to filter you result. 
And then use [usort](http://php.net/usort) to sort by the distance.

In example:

```
function filter_function($takeaway) {
  return $takeaway->someProperty == 1; // could be your menu;
}

function sort_function($a, $b) {
  // distance must be set before elements are passed trough the sort function
  $ad = $a->distance;
  $bd = $b->distance;

  // sort is ASC 
  if ($ad == $bd) {
      return 0;
  }
  // todo DESC change the < operator to >
  return ($ad < $bd) ? -1 : 1;  
}

$takeaways = array_filter($takeaways, filter_function);
usort($takeaways, sort_function);
```